# How do I make my pc speaker beep

Tags: command-line, audio

Using bash, how can I make the pc speaker beep?

Something like `echo 'beepsound' > /dev/pcspkr` would be nice.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker || http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313939/how-to-emit-a-beep-on-my-computer-while-running-a-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: I searched everywhere and tried everything I could to try and get this to work a few years ago, and finally gave up settling to play a sound file instead.  *But a bug must have been fixed.*  Because now when I open GNOME ALSA Mixer I see a new slider for 'Beep' with a muted checkbox.  When enabled I now have a beep!  Perhaps too much it beeps, lol, but my lovely Debian Buster finally beeps.  It even beeps in TTY modes (via Ctl-Alt F1).  Tested w/ something like echo -e "\a".

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I usually use the little utility `beep` installed on many systems.
This command will try different approaches to create a system sound.

There are 3 ways of creating a sound from the `beep` manpage:

1. The traditional method of producing a beep in a shell script is to write an `ASCII BEL` (`\007`) character to standard output, by means of a shell command such as

   ```
   echo -ne '\007'
   ```

   This only  works if the calling shell's standard output is currently directed to a terminal device of some sort; if not, the beep will produce no sound and might even cause unwanted corruption in whatever file the output is directed to.
2. There are other ways to cause a beeping noise. A slightly more reliable method is to open `/dev/tty` and send your BEL character there. This is robust against I/O redirection, but still fails in the case where the shell script wishing to generate a beep does not have a controlling terminal, for example because it is run from an X window  manager.
3. A third approach is to connect to your X display and send it a bell command. This does not depend on a Unix terminal device, but does (of course) require an X display.

`beep` will simply try these 3 methods.

Comment: The homepage to the `beep` command is: http://johnath.com/beep/  On Ubuntu/Debian, you can install it with `apt-get install beep`.

Comment: On linux, there is a fourth badass method for beeping: unload the `pcspkr` module, load the `snd-pcsp`, and you now have a alsa soundcard that uses old-school tricks to actually feed digital sound to your internal speaker. It gives crappy results with piezoelectric internal speakers, but on classical internal speakers, the quality is quite good for what it is. This way, you can get much more creative for your beep sounds ;)

Comment: @BatchyX In Ubuntu 12.04 I `apt-cache search`ed for `pcspkr` and `snd-pcsp` with no results. `apt-cache search pc speaker` gives some results but nothing that looks relevant.

Comment: @isomorphismes: `pcspkr` and `snd-pcsp` are modules, not packages. use `modprobe`/`modprobe -r`/`lsmod` to manipulate them.  For your information, they are in the `linux-image-something` package, which is hopefully already installed (or else you would have no linux kernel).

Comment: beep usually works out the box for debian but I needed to load the module for this to work on ubuntu

Comment: I entered a string of mysql database imports on a single line in bash, and then found myself wishing there was some way to make linux notify me when they were all finished. Next time, I will have a way! Btw, I tried `# beep` on Centos 6, but it didn't work. `# echo -ne '\007'` did work though. (And so did `# echo -e "\007"`)

Comment: As mchid said, after adding the module: `modprobe snd-pcsp`, beep is now working!

Comment: What do you mean by open `/dev/tty`? I tried `echo -ne "\007" > /dev/tty`, and it produced no audible effect.

Comment: `echo -ne "\007"` works on a Ubuntu 18.04 box, but `modprobe snd-pcs` throws a a "FATAL" error

Comment: This answer assumes unrealistic environment... who has X server client today? and the 'beep' command is not built in bash (at least not in its Mac OS X version)

Comment: Be warned that the Debian `beep` command *only* uses the internal speaker, so option 3 of this answer is ruled out. `beep` does not work on devices without a pc speaker. For example an Intel NUC does not have an internal speaker; you can emulate one by setting a BIOS option and plugging an external speaker in the front plug.

Answer (score 127):

*NOTE: This solution emits beeps from the **speakers**, not the **motherboard**.*

ALSA comes with [speaker-test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/speaker-test), a command-line speaker test tone generator, which can be used to generate a beep:

```
$ speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -l 1
```

See [this arch linux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=806848#p806848).

However, the beep duration will be arbitrary, but can be controlled as follows:

```
$ ( speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 )& pid=$! ; sleep 0.1s ; kill -9 $pid
```

We can take it one step further and output a beep with this function:

```
_alarm() {
  ( \speaker-test --frequency $1 --test sine )&
  pid=$!
  \sleep 0.${2}s
  \kill -9 $pid
}
```

which is called with frequency and duration arguments:

```
$ _alarm 400 200
```

With this in mind, it is possible to create simple music with `speaker-test`. See [this shell script](https://github.com/spiralofhope/shell-random/blob/master/live/sh/scripts/alarm.sh).

Comment: Your function as one-liner (and Ctrl-C compatible): `timeout ${2} speaker-test --frequency ${1} --test sine`

Comment: There's no real need to save pid, just `speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -l 1 & sleep .2 && kill -9 $!
` does the same thing. Anyway, @user569825's method is nicer.

Comment: Ouch, that hurts.

Comment: On my system (ubuntu 16.04), timeout needs to have `-s` set to some signal because speaker-test doesn't respect sig term.

Comment: @RyneEverett your [alarm.sh](https://github.com/spiralofhope/shell-random/blob/master/live/alarm.sh) is maybe now here ? [alarm.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spiralofhope/shell-random/master/live/sh/scripts/alarm.sh)

Comment: I made this convenient alias using @m3nda's comment: `alias beep='( speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -l 1 >/dev/null & sleep .1 && kill -9 $! )'`... seems to work well :)

Answer (score 93):

Simply echoing `\a` or `\07` works for me.

```
$ echo -e "\a"
```

This will probably require the `pcspkr` kernel module to be loaded. I've only tested this on RHEL, so YMMV.

#### UPDATE

As Warren pointed out in the comments, this may not work when logged in remotely via SSH. A quick workaround would be to redirect the output to any of the TTY devices (ideally one that is unused). E.g.:

```
$ echo -en "\a" > /dev/tty5
```

Comment: If you're using an X terminal or ssh'd into the machine, this may just cause the terminal to flash, since many xterm/vt100 type programs are configured to do that for BEL characters.

Comment: @warren. Good point, will update answer.

Comment: This makes sense but it didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @isomorphismes: that's for consoles, not X11 terminals. For beeps under X, you may try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/587311/11015

Comment: @MestreLion Thank you. BTW, I had tried it in console (VT) as well.

Comment: @isomorphismes: I'm also using Ubuntu 12.04, and for me `sudo modprobe pcspkr` was enough to enable beeps under the VT, either via `printf "\a"` or `beep` utility.

Comment: This works fine on a Mac terminal.

Comment: `echo -e "\a"` works on my remote terminal for CentOS 6. But I think I'll find it easier to remember `echo -e "\007"`. -Bond, James Bond.

Comment: The `echo` command is a shell built-in in many shells like dash, bash or zsh and will be used instead of the system provided `/bin/echo` program. Unforunately, some shells (especially POSIX shells like dash, which provides `sh` on some operating systems) do not offer the `-e` argument for `echo`. Thus, instead of recommending to run `echo -e "\a"` you should either recommend running `/bin/echo -e "\a"` (if the system has GNU echo installed) or `printf "\a"` or plainly `echo "\a"` which will also work in POSIX compliant shells because the shell interprets the backslash escape and not echo.

Comment: None of the methods work for me. `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`

Comment: @ar2015: Are you sure your PC has a speaker? This is not working for me either, but I never get beeps anyway.

Comment: @einpoklum, Yes, I do have a speaker both on my laptop and PC both under `Ubuntu` and none of the methods work on them.

Comment: This works if you have an X display as it opens up an xterm and plays the beep to it a number of times. Fiddle with the '3' value and the '0.25' to your hearts content: `xterm -e sh -c 'for i in $(seq 3); do echo -e "\a"; sleep .25; done'`

Answer (score 54):

```
tput bel
```

because **terminfo** defines `bel` as

```
           Variable                       Cap-               TCap                  Description
            String                        name               Code

   bell                                   bel                bl                audible signal
                                                                               (bell) (P)
```

Answer (score 43):

For using the soundcard if `sox` is installed and the PC speaker if not:

```
$ play -q -n synth 0.1 sin 880 || echo -e "\a"
```

`sox` is available for most distros.

Comment: +1 I did not know that play had this feature. I ended up using this in a `then` block within `watch` to notify me once a certain condition was met.   Even lets me keep my headphones on.  This was very useful to me.

Comment: From a bash sh play will probably need `sudo -u USER play...`

Comment: On my system, `play` uses pulseaudio, as a user. I guess it depends on system configuration.

Comment: This is a great solution. Not only does it work without having to load any modules in any terminal but it's also very variable. You could have a script have different notifcation sounds very easily. Changing the `0.1` will change the length of the sound, lots of possibilities! (Make sure to run this script as the user under which pulseaudio is running, if you use pulseaudio. If you don't or can't, there are two workarounds. One is to run PA system wide (not recommended), one is to allow other users to access PA.)

Comment: if you get warning: `play WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable` then you should do `export AUDIODRIVER=alsa` to remove the warning.  Cheers!

Answer (score 21):

"**Beep can only work if your PC has a traditional old style "speaker"**, and probably most if not all laptops and small devices don't have one.

However what they often have instead is a sound chip and one or more speaker(s) that can be used to make any sound you want.

So the outdated advise to install the `beep` command and/or the kernel module `pcspkr` will silently never work when you don't have the old style speaker hardware.

**INSTEAD:**  Try playing a sound like this when you want a beep:

```
paplay /usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/capital
```

Note this uses the `paplay` (**P**ulse **A**udio **Play**) command which mixes better with other user level (user app) sounds on your system, and not the older `aplay` (**A**LSA **Play**) command which generally can only play one sound at the same time.  But note however, that PulseAudio calls ALSA to actually play the sound.

*My previous suggestion to use `play` might still work, but running SoX of which play is from, is overkill.*

---

Works for me when all else failed.  Thanks to: [tredegar](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-play-beep-sound-inside-shell-script-895465/#post4433944) & [hk_centos](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-play-beep-sound-inside-shell-script-895465/#post4434270) and others.

Comment: Nice! The command is available on a fresh (rather) installation of Linux Mint 20.

Comment: Now that PipeWire has replaced PulseAudio, should this answer be updated? Or, should we just go back to using `play` from sox since it works the same way on all Unix systems?

Answer (score 14):

Some distros have command-line utilities to achieve this. Maybe you could tell us what distro you are on, or search (e.g. `emerge -s beep` in gentoo).

Going beyond "available" utils, you could also make a Perl script that emits the beep, all you need to do is include:

```
<SomeCodeBefore>
print "\007";
<SomeCodeAfter>
```

If you do end up getting 'beep', try out the following:

```
#! /bin/sh 

beep -f 500 -l 700 
beep -f 480 -l 400 
beep -f 470 -l 250 
beep -f 530 -l 300 -D 100 
beep -f 500 -l 300 -D 100 
beep -f 500 -l 300 
beep -f 400 -l 600 
beep -f 300 -l 500 
beep -f 350 -l 700 
beep -f 250 -l 600
```

Comment: I like my questions to remain distro-agnostic, would `echo -e "\007"` work in bash instead of `print "\007` in perl?

Comment: @Stefan - Beep is pretty much 'universal'. You can, however, remain distro agnostic by using 'echo -e "\a"' or 'echo -e "\07"'. Cheers!

Comment: It would be more portable to use `printf '\007'` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, tools like [`beep`](https://github.com/johnath/beep/) can use an ioctl on the console device to emit a given sound. To be more specific, `beep` will use the `KIOCSOUND` ioctl, but there is also a `KDMKTONE` ioctl which can be used to generate sound.

As I understand it, the former starts a sound which lasts until it's explicitly cancelled, while the latter will create a beep of pre-determined duration. See [the `console_ioctl`(4) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/console_ioctl) for details.

So if you are unhappy with what `beep` does, you could write a few lines of code to access these ioctls directly. Assuming you have full access to `/dev/console`, which might well require root privileges.

Comment: Only works if an internal speaker is available

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo -n Ctrl+V Ctrl+G
```

The downside is that this will work only when the output device is a terminal, so it may not work inside a cron job, for instance. (But if you are root you might be able redirect to `/dev/console` for immediate beeping.)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me on mint (thanks to @alexander above)

```
alias beep='play -q -n synth 0.1 sin 880 >& /dev/null'
```

Comment: Worked for me on Debian, and I just put that line in a little bash script, and installed it with full path and a dummy argument in Alacritty, in the bell section.

Comment: Just FYI, that will only work if `sox` is installed on the Mint system.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: In my terminal (gnome-terminal), it works without the Enter. Just as a test of PC speaker, this looks fine to me. It is utterly useless in scripts, though.

Comment: Surprising downvotes. This does work on some PC's, it might not work on all though.

Comment: It doesn't work on rxvt, urxvt, xterm, lxterm or lxterminal, shouldn't my terminal at least flash if it has a visual bell?

Comment: It does work on xterm

Answer (score -1):

**KDE Plasma (5.18) Konsole app**

Settings (menu) > Configure Notifications > Bell in Focused Session

Check "play a sound" and select an associated audio file

```
echo -e "\a"
```

etc should then work.