# Is there a checklist for getting the "beep" program to work?

Tags: linux, audio

Debian has a program called "beep" available, that lets you make the computer beep at whatever frequency or time you want. http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/beep

The problem that many people seem to have is that they don't want their computers to beep, so they complain about the beeps, and then the default gets set to things like pcspkr module getting blacklisted and other stuff that stops beeping, and unfortunately stops the beep program from working.

I want beep to work! I like being able to make the computer beep for various reasons. But I don't know all the things to check to figure out why it doesn't work, so I go for workarounds like getting wav files and playing them. I would much rather just get beep to work!

Does anybody know all the things that have to be checked to get beep to work? Already I've checked that the pcspkr module isn't blacklisted and is loaded, and checked the volume levels and muting using alsamixer. But still no beeps. How can I make my computers beep please?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep?rq=1

Comment: Playing files to get beeps to work may cause programs to have highly variable execution times.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your computer has a beeper in it. Some don't.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I did exactly the same things on two different computers, one beeps, the other doesn't. Not sure how else to tell if a computer has a beeper in it though.

Comment: Look on the motherboard. The beeper should be a small round black thing with a hole in the middle. There should be a silvery thing inside the hole.