# motherboard beep

Tags: debian, audio, bios

I am using a Debian machine, ARK-3360F, and I need to make it beep like it does when it starts-up. Unfortunately, there is not any other speaker than this on the machine, so the below methods do not work even if I use `modprobe pcspkr`:

```
echo -e "\a"
echo ^G
echo -e "\07"
```

-and the *beep* program

Comment: Try `modprobe pcspkr` and `printf '\a' > /dev/tty1`

Comment: I used `echo -e` instead of `printf` since it is in terminal and not C. Still it doesn't beep.

Comment: @Alex: You can use `printf` in various shells. Checked `alsamixer`?

Comment: sorry you are right. However, `printf` didn't work and so does the `beep` program.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, somehow missed that you had tested with `beep`. Checked `alsamixer`? Here are some ways to [*mute beep*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_Speaker_Beep) – but you might find some of it useful.

Comment: I tried but there is no such package for a non-graphic Debian in the apt-cache.

Comment: Does it beep on BOOT? As in: sure it actually has a speaker? If it has, and `beep` does not beep, it mostly sound slike a mute issue. You could also try with `snd-pcsp` as [noted here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep?lq=1#comment87963_1980). This should give an extra entry for `pcsp` in ALSA. If no `alsamixer` try `amixer`.

Comment: @Sukminder: that worked! thank you very much

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep

Answer (score 4):

As root echo to /dev/console:

```
 echo -e '\a' > /dev/console
```

or as normal user:

```
sudo bash -c "echo -e '\a' > /dev/console"
```

as indicated you may have to run `sudo modprobe pcspkr` first.

Comment: this works on my laptop which has normal speakers but not on the Debian machine. Unfortunately, the sound doesn't come from the motherboard speaker but from the normal speakers.