# Command "beep" does not do anything

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, alsamixer

I have an old Dell Latitude E5430 laptop running DietPi Native PC (x86_64). *DietPi is a fork of Debian 11 Bullseye.

### Summary

Today, I installed beep and ran it. It put me back into bash a second later. There was no sound. Strangely though, using a terminal music player called "cmus", sound actually works and it play with no problem.

### What did I try

- I installed the latest Linux Intel sound card drivers
- I installed ALSA
- I set the volume to maximum in ALSA Mixer

### Additional info

Inside of my /etc/asound.conf:

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm {
                type hw
                card 0
                device 0
        }
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

I confirmed that the speaker is connected.

Comment: This answers your question: [How do I make my pc speaker beep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep)

Answer (score 0):

This command is used to control speaker, not sound card. So if on your computer you have no connected speaker you can expect to hear nothing.

To quoting one commend:

> small piezoelectric buzzer/speaker usually connected through two wires
> directly to the motherboard and installed internally, not external
> speakers you plug in

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Yes my speaker is connected and is functional as said in the original question.

Comment: Its _not_ any external speaker that matters here, `beep` beeps the small piezoelectric buzzer/speaker usually connected through two wires directly to the motherboard and installed internally, not external speakers you plug in.

Comment: Did you see more than about 10 sound channels in the `alsamixer`? If not, try pressing F6 and selecting a specific soundcard instead of "default" (which could be the simplified mixer provided by Pulseaudio). When you get the actual hardware mixer of the sound card/chip, it should have a large number of channels with independent volume and/or mute settings. One of those might be labelled something like "Beep". It is usually muted and at volume 0 by default. Unmute that and turn its volume up, then try the `beep` command again.

Comment: Also, you may have to add yourself to the `input` group to be able to use the `beep` command, unless you are root (`sudo usermod -a -G input $(whoami)`)

Comment: Unfortunately, some laptops simply don't wire the beeper/buzzer output of the system chipset into the sound chip and don't provide a classic (pre-soundcard) physical PC buzzer/beeper at all. So it is possible you are simply out of luck with your current hardware. Then you'll have to use something like `aplay beep.wav` instead.